# Parsing Dynamic Data in Sparklines

Tags: php, mysql

I want to parse dynamic data in sparklines.
My code:

```
$(".daily-visitors").sparkline([1,5,5.5,5.4,5.8,6,8,9,13,12,10,11.5,9,8,5,8,9], {
  type: 'line',
  width: '100%',
  height: '55',
  lineColor: '#ff4e50',
  fillColor: '#ffd2d3',
  lineWidth: 2,
  spotColor: '#a9282a',
  minSpotColor: '#a9282a',
  maxSpotColor: '#a9282a',
  highlightSpotColor: '#a9282a',
  highlightLineColor: '#f4c3c4',
  spotRadius: 2,
  drawNormalOnTop: true
 });
```

I want dynamic data from MYSQL by using PHP.

Comment: format your code please

Comment: what you have tried so far? please post some code

Comment: I have tried it Successfully once, Here I used Data.php for data parsing..
But this is different sort of syntax...

Before That I did this to fetch 2 columns from database and show them in Highcharts Graph

Comment: try using ajax and put your code in onsuccess and set values dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest a new php file where you'd be getting JSON data from using POST request.
Example query:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT daily_visitors FROM stats ORDER BY when DESC LIMIT 30");
```

Then you prepare it for sparklines to display. After fetching the array you can do something like this and return the data in JSON format:

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

Which would be equivalent to something like this:

```
[1,5,5.5,5.4,5.8,6,8,9,13,12,10,11.5,9,8,5,8,9]
```

You can then POST request this data from your website:

```
$.post("url to your php file", { examplePostArgument:"test" }, function(data){
$(".daily-visitors").sparkline(data, {
    type: 'line',
    width: '100%',
    height: '55',
    lineColor: '#ff4e50',
    fillColor: '#ffd2d3',
    lineWidth: 2,
    spotColor: '#a9282a',
    minSpotColor: '#a9282a',
    maxSpotColor: '#a9282a',
    highlightSpotColor: '#a9282a',
    highlightLineColor: '#f4c3c4',
    spotRadius: 2,
    drawNormalOnTop: true
 });
});
```

This examplePostArgument will be accessible in your PHP file using this superglobal array:

```
$_POST["examplePostArgument"];
```

Comment: Nikon.. I appreciate your help and I will try it, then I will inform you about the outcomes..

Comment: Hi Nikon.. I had a weekend.. Now I am trying your method, So far I have successful in retrieving data in separate file trough json in array form.. But it is not shown in my chart.. may be something wrong with calling

Comment: And Finally I have done it... after a long struggle ..
There is no need of $_POST["examplePostArgument"];
And use this instead...
$.getJSON("json.php", function(data){
Anyway many thanks for helping..

Comment: yeah you didn't need an example argument, just showed you you could do that if you needed to pass additional data to your backend